# Need to figure out how to have a countdown in PHP

Tags: php

I have a timestamp and would like to show my users... last sent 1 day, 23 hours, 54 minutes, and 33 seconds ago. I know how to get the difference in time...

```
$timePast = '2012-08-18 22:11:33';
$timeNow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
// gives total seconds difference
$timeDiff = strtotime($timeNow) - strtotime($timePast);
```

Now I am stuck not being able to show the time like above.
x day, x hours, x mins, x seconds where all the x's should add up to the total seconds time difference. I know the following...

```
$lastSent['h'] = round($timeDiff / 3600);
$lastSent['m'] = round($timeDiff / 60);
$lastSent['s'] = $timeDiff;
```

Need you help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 1):

After this:

```
$timeDiff = strtotime($timeNow) - strtotime($timePast);
```

add:

```
if ($timeDiff > (60*60*24)) {$timeDiff = floor($timeDiff/60/60/24) . ' days ago';}
else if ($timeDiff > (60*60)) {$timeDiff = floor($timeDiff/60/60) . ' hours ago';}
else if ($timeDiff > 60) {$timeDiff = floor($timeDiff/60) . ' minutes ago';}
else if ($timeDiff > 0) {$timeDiff .= ' seconds ago';}

echo $timeDiff;
```

Comment: floor() would be a better solution than round()

Comment: Your code will return just "2 days ago" when he wants it to return "2 days, 3 hours and 35 minutes ago"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did need what alfasin said but was able to figure it out using your logic Kalpesh.

Comment: @KalpeshMehta Don't forget to upvote helpful posts/comments and mark an answer for your question

Comment: @charlieg Sorry?? I have not asked this question dude.

Answer (score 1):

I took Kalpesh's code and made it work by using `floor` instead of `round` and by calculating the different frictions of the day. Here it goes:

```
function timeAgo ($oldTime, $newTime) {
    $timeCalc = strtotime($newTime) - strtotime($oldTime);
    $ans = "";
    if ($timeCalc > 60*60*24) {        
        $days = floor($timeCalc/60/60/24);
        $ans .=  "$days days"; 
        $timeCalc = $timeCalc - ($days * (60*60*24));        
    }
    if ($timeCalc > 60*60) {
        $hours = floor($timeCalc/60/60);
        $ans .=  ", $hours hours"; 
        $timeCalc = $timeCalc - ($hours * (60*60));        
    }
    if ($timeCalc > 60) {
        $minutes = floor($timeCalc/60);
        $ans .=  ", $minutes minutes"; 
        $timeCalc = $timeCalc - ($minutes * 60);        
    }    
    if ($timeCalc > 0) {
        $ans .= "and $timeCalc seconds";        
    }
    return $ans . " ago";
} 
$timePast = '2012-08-18 22:11:33';
$timeNow = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');    
$t = timeAgo($timePast, $timeNow);
echo $t;
```

**Output**:
1 days, 16 hours, 11 minutes and 18 seconds ago

Comment: That is actually exactly what I needed. Thank you all for your great responses.

Answer (score 1):

## Don't do date math manually!

PHP can work out all of the date/time math for you, using the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/dateinterval) classes.

#### Getting an interval between two dates

```
$timePast = new DateTime('2012-08-18 22:11:33');
$timeNow  = new DateTime;

$lastSent = $timePast->diff($timeNow);
// $lastSent is a DateInterval with properties for the years, months, etc.
```

#### Formatting example

A function for getting a formatted string might look like the following (though this is only one super-basic way, of many).

```
function format_interval(DateInterval $interval) {
    $units = array('y' => 'years', 'm' => 'months', 'd' => 'days',
                   'h' => 'hours', 'i' => 'minutes', 's' => 'seconds');
    $parts = array();
    foreach ($units as $part => $label) {
        if ($interval->$part > 0) {
            $parts[] = $interval->$part . ' ' . $units[$part];
        }
    }
    return implode(', ', $parts);
}

echo format_interval($lastSent); // e.g. 2 days, 24 minutes, 46 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a lot of [if's](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php), the [modulus (%)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), [floor()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) (not round())

Or [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php%20human%20readable%20time%20difference) ;-)