# Calculating days hours and minutes php

Tags: php, time, milliseconds

Alright, so I send an integer to my mysql database that's in milliseconds. Now, I'm trying to make it so that it says: Time Played: 1 day 3 hours and 15 minutes.
But I'm having a hard time doing it, I just am able to get the minutes days and hours, but it'd be the amount of hours total the amount of days total and the minutes total, not all in one. I have my code like this:

```
$time = $timeRow['time'];    
$seconds = floor($time / 1000);
$minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
$hours = floor($minutes / 60);
$days = round($hours / 24);
$milliseconds = $time % 1000;
$seconds = $seconds % 60;
$minutes = $minutes % 60;
echo'Time Played: '.$days.' days '.$hours.' hours '.$minutes.' minutes';
```

Could anyone help me fix this up?

Comment: Stand on the shoulders of giants, use [PHP DateTime stuff](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php).

Comment: You can use the answer I gave [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12045387/1057429)

Comment: @moonwave99 and how does it help?

Comment: @alfasin - It's a much more flexible and versatile class for dealing with date and time display / calculations / manipulations in PHP.

Comment: @nickb I think that it would be better if he posted [*this*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) link

Comment: @alfasin - create a `DateInterval` with the millisecs, and you get all the time subunits, for example. By the way I posted the main datetime reference which includes both procedural and OO style docs - up to the reader to choose.

Comment: @moonwave99 then you should post a link to [*DateInterval*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and say that you recommend to go over all [*datetime*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) library. Sending a link to the library (that probably has ~100 items) is too vogue. But then again, maybe it's just me...

Comment: @alfasin it has 5 elements [4 classes, 1 function], which is << 100. Thanks for narrowing down, anyway ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php

$time = $timeRow['time'] / 1000;

$days = floor($time / (24*60*60));
$hours = floor(($time - ($days*24*60*60)) / (60*60));
$minutes = floor(($time - ($days*24*60*60)-($hours*60*60)) / 60);
$seconds = ($time - ($days*24*60*60) - ($hours*60*60) - ($minutes*60)) % 60;

echo'Time Played: '.$days.' days '.$hours.' hours '.$minutes.' minutes '.$seconds.' seconds';
```

Test: http://codepad.viper-7.com/WBQQet

Comment: @BrandonTylerJones Yeah, this calculations make me headache from many years :))

Answer (score -1):

You're generating each variable from the original number, which is why it's telling you it's 1 day, and 35 hours; instead of 1 day and 11 hours.

You need to start subtracting values:

```
$seconds = floor($time / 1000);
$minutes = floor($seconds / 60);
$hours = floor($minutes / 60);
$days = round($hours / 24);

for ($i = 0; $i < $days; $i++) {
    $hours -= 24;
}
```

And a similar piece of code for hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski - What do you mean? I know it's not very efficient, but it runs and produces what seems to be the right output.

Comment: @BrandonTylerJones - Ah, the for loop needs to start at 0

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski - thanks. I'm quite happy for people to criticize my code and tell me it's wrong, but if you don't say _why_ it's wrong, it's really not going to help.

Comment: You're going to have to justify that. I got the wrong value for the for loop, and fixed it. That's long way from there being no logic in the code. It might not be an efficient logic, but it's there.